# android menu not shown

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to study a project from [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-JY-MCU-Module-Bluetooth-Android-Applicatio/?ALLSTEPS). After I downloaded the android app code and added the gridle files(the original gridle files are missing ), the mainActivity doesn't have the menu at the top of the screen.

the menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/secure_connect_scan"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:title="@string/secure_connect"
      app:showAsAction="always" />
```

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here's a link to the code : [github](https://github.com/wilsonandusa/TextbookReader/tree/master/TextbookReader)

[image: it should look like this]

[image]

Comment: How did you add the gradle files?

Comment: @RichArt I first created a new android project and then added all the activity, manifest files and the res folder

Comment: Did you add any file manually?

Comment: no if you check the github links, all the files are from the original project page

Comment: Let me know if my answer below helped. Maybe point 5 is the key :-)

Comment: Do you mean the ActionBar? The bar at the top of the Screen, that is missing in the bottom Image? In that case, I think that is related to Android Lollipop and later versions. Have you tried with KitKat? Is just to check if the bar problem is related with Android version.

Comment: I tried with Marshmallow (6.0.1)

Comment: But since the whole app is targeted to Kitkat (API 19) it should work with Kitkat and upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried and everything works fine. The menu bar is there. Do following:

1. Delete all project files to start from the scratch again.
2. `git clone https://github.com/aso777/BlueControl.git` into the location you want to have the project. (Or just download the zip file from git, unzip it, and move it to the right place.)
3. Open Android Studio
4. On the Welcome screen click on "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)" (it's the 4th option!)
5. Select the inner(!!) BlueControl folder and click OK.
6. Accept all standard conficuration with "next" and "finalize".
7. It you get import errors, just accept the fix Android Studio is proposing. (you may have to download some API stuff.)

OK?

Answer (score 0):

you are using AppCompat theme but extending Activity. So, please change the following line

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```